# Calling load with attribute name - $product->load('attribute_name');

Tags: product, product-attribute

Looking through one of the projects I've been working on, I keep coming across code that does `$product->load('attribute_name')`, where product is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. Digging down through the code for a product model, I fail to see what this is supposed to do. Is this just a misunderstanding by whoever wrote this custom code, or am I missing something?

As far as I'm concerned this would attempt to load a product with the id of 'attribute_code', which doesn't exist. In this situation it would hit `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::load` with `$product, 'attribute_code', array()` as the arguments. This would actually mark the current model as new with `isObjectNew(true)` since it can't be loaded from the database, but since `$attributes` is empty it will trigger `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::loadAllAttributes`, which due to the fact the model was partly loaded and thus contains an entity_id already, fetches all attributes from the database for that `entity_id`. If this is the case, the string `'attribute_code'` is somewhat irrelevant (so long as it isn't the entity_id of another product) and all attributes will be loaded for the entity_id contained in the model.

Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, yes what you are suggesting is correct. The select statement built when calling the load in you question would be the following.

```
SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (entity_id ='attribute_name')
```

You can find this out by adding some debug into the load method in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract`

If you are actually wanting to load a product via an attribute that is not `entity_id` the the following snippet would do it.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'My Sku Value');
```

*NOTE: with `loadByAttribute` if the attribute is not unique then the first object found will be returned*

*SECOND NOTE: this will return either an `object` or `false` (thanks Fabian)*

Comment: FYI if no model is found, false is returned (NOT a new object!)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Thanks I have added a second note

Comment: Be aware that loadByAttribute() does not trigger the usual events that load() does, which may cause issues if other areas of the codebase are relying on those events.

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to David Manners ...**

> If you are actually wanting to load a product via an attribute that is
>   not `entity_id` the the following snippet would do it.
>
> ```
> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'My Sku Value');
> ```

To speed up loading you should take care of `loadByAttribute` 3rd parameter.

<sup>https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.3.x/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php#L216-L235</sup>

```
/**
 * Load entity by attribute
 *
 * @param Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Interface|integer|string|array $attribute
 * @param null|string|array $value
 * @param string $additionalAttributes
 * @return bool|Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
 */
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Set `$additionalAttributes` to `null` (just default attributes) or `array('your', 'attributes', 'here')` for your own.

```
$attributesToSelect = array('name');
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'My Sku Value', $attributesToSelect);
```